# Early 90s mecha anime where the mecha was like Voltron in that each pilot controlled a portion of the mecha that would merge into a bigger mecha

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I'm trying to find an anime movie I watched when I was younger; I believe I first watched it in 90/91. The story revolved around the recruitment and training of a group that would pilot a mecha that was similar to Voltron in that each pilot controlled a portion of the mecha that would merge into a bigger mecha. Points that I remember:

- Started on Earth
- Program was government funded
- One of the pilots was related to the creator of the program, I think a female
- Mecha had chain weapon and a sword that was summoned from it's superhero-like chest icon. Killing blow was an m or w shape
- Ended with father/creator of mecha? being kidnapped by the aliens and used as human shield to deter attack on alien vessel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *Chōdenji Machine Voltes V* (1977).

#### Started on Earth

In this anime, Earth is invaded by alien "Boazanians".

#### Merging parts of a mech

The robot used to fight these aliens is called Voltes V. It has five parts connected to each other,  with a different pilot for each.

#### Government-funded

The "United Nations Earth Defense Force" helped build the robot.

#### Female pilot related to the program's creator

Megumi Oka is General Oka's daughter and one of the pilots; General Oka worked on making the mech.

#### Creator of the robot dies

> General Oka dies saving Megumi from a Boazanian.

<sub>Note:  Info is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Ddenji_Machine_Voltes_V).</sub>

Comment: Note: I made this answer because this is a target for another question that is a duplicate and I wanted to have more details in the description; the question's asker found it.

Answer (score 8):

*Voltes V* is the movie I was looking for.

I found [*Combattler V*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Ddenji_Robo_Combattler_V) on the [page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158064/early-90s-mecha-anime#comment414788_158064) FuzzyBoots linked. It has similar art to, and is the precursor of, [*Voltes V*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Ddenji_Machine_Voltes_V).

> An armada of horned humanoid aliens known as Boazanians invade Earth and launch their "beast fighters" all over the world, defeating most of the world's armed forces. The Boazanians first defeat from the hands of Super Electromagnetic Machine Voltes V brings the invaders to focus their attacks on Japan. Voltes V was designed by Professor Kentaro Gō (Doctor Ned Armstrong), his wife Professor Mitsuyo Gō (Doctor Mary Ann Armstrong) and their trusted colleague, Professor Hamaguchi (Doctor Richard Smith) and built by large scale construction effort backed by United Nations Earth Defense Force and General Oka (Commander Robinson). Voltes V is a robot composed of five "Volt Machines", and each are themselves formidable weapons. Each machine is piloted by Ken'ichi (Steve), Daijiro (Big Bert), and Hiyoshi (Little Jon): the three sons of Kentaro and Mitsuyo Gō, along with General Oka's daughter; Megumi (Jamie Robinson), and Ippei Mine (Mark Gordon), an orphan cowboy.

Now I'm looking for a modern translation or sub so I can experience it again.

Comment: I'm aware it's your own answer, but can you provide some more details which may 1. make it more likely for other people who search google to find your answer, and 2. to make them see more details which might confirm to them that this is the anime they're looking for.